# Footer não permance abaixo do Body, e hover de botões aciona sem o cursor estar em cima

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou tendo um problema já há alguns dias, tentei resolver de várias maneiras, já tentei mudar o "position" de "relative" pra "fixed" e "absolute", antes eu não tinha um "wrapper", na verdade até agora não sei pra que serve, mas já mudei aquelas coisas sem e com o "wrapper" e não mudou nada, estava tendo outro problema com um espaço branco em baixo do "footer", e que se tornava mais evidente quando dava zoom. Olhei em alguns fórums e em várias perguntas aqui no stack overflow em inglês e ninguém também conseguia resolver o problema desse maldito footer, acredito que algumas pessoas já tiveram que lidar com isso também ashasuhuashu disseram que tem como resolver com JavaScript, mas acho ridículo um problema de estrutura do HTML/CSS só poder ser resolvido com JS, tenho quase certeza que tem algum modo de resolver sem utilizá-lo, mas já faz alguns dias que tô agarrado nisso sem saber resolver então resolvi perguntar.

Outro problema tá sendo o "hover" dos botões inferiores, os de telefone e currículo, está sendo acionado mesmo quando a seta passasse ao lado do botão, coisa que não deveria estar acontecendo, imagino que seja algo relacionado com a "div" ou até mesmo com a "li", não dá pra tirá-los pois preciso que o "href" envolva todo o botão e não somente o texto de dentro do botão, afinal, não seria um botão assim ashasusahu

PS: O site está em fase "beta", não o estou utilizando como portfolio, fiquem tranquilos, é só pra treino pois não me aprofundei em algumas das linguagens que citei no "Competências". Desde já grato à quem puder dedicar seu tempo pra responder às minhas dúvidas!!!

Link do site: hykky.com.br

Comment: Bem-vindo, você pode começar fazendo [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e para obter respostas que solucionem sua dúvida / problema leia [Como fazer uma boa pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) e [Como formatar minhas publicações usando o Markdown ou HTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Não entendi o problema do footer, o dos botôes precisa ver o css, provavelmente sua UL está ocupando mais do que deveria, considere visitar os links do comentário acima e [edit] sua questão para evitar o fechamento, e assim aparecerem soluções e respostas...Boa Sorte!

Comment: O espaço entre o footer e os botões está gigante, apesar de não ter nenhum padding ou height no footer ou nos botões pra dar esse espaço, pode-se perceber isso também quando se dá zoom na página, o espaço acaba se tornando cada vez maior. Quanto ao dos botões eu vou dar uma fuçada no ul pra ver se consigo resolver

Comment: Você está utilizando algum framework CSS? Testou em telas menores?

Comment: Nope, CSS puro, nada de pegar coisa pronta na hora de aprender ashsauhu e não testei em telas menores, mas é exatamente por isso que testei o zoom, porque quero que o site seja flexível quando se deparar com resoluções menores e maiores. =(

Comment: O wrapper está `min-height:100%` forçando o footer ficar fora da tela.

Comment: Sim, mas quando eu retiro persiste o problema do espaço branco em baixo do footer e o footer não fica colado com a parte de baixo do site =(